# Making pictures change slowly in html/ css / javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I am using this code to change images after time interval. Naturally, they disappear very fast and it's not so nice. How can make it more slowly and pretty?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script type='text/javascript'>
var imageID=0;
function changeimage(every_seconds){
    //change the image
    if(!imageID){
        document.getElementById("myimage").src="http://www.all-freeware.com/images/full/38943-nice_feathers_free_screensaver_desktop_screen_savers__nature.jpeg";
        imageID++;
    }
    else{if(imageID==1){
        document.getElementById("myimage").src="http://www.hickerphoto.com/data/media/186/flower-bouquet-nice_12128.jpg";
        imageID++;
    }else{if(imageID==2){
        document.getElementById("myimage").src="http://www.photos.a-vsp.com/fotodb/14_green_cones.jpg";
        imageID=0;
    }}}
    //call same function again for x of seconds
    setTimeout("changeimage("+every_seconds+")",((every_seconds)*1000));
}
</script>
</head>
<body style='background:black;' onload='changeimage(2)'>
<div style='position:absolute;width:100%;height:100%;left:0px;top:0px;' align='center'><img width='300px' height='250px' id='myimage' src='http://www.photos.a-vsp.com/fotodb/14_green_cones.jpg'/></div>
</body></html>
```

Comment: You tagged it with jquery but you don't seem to ever use it. There are tons of examples of this kind of thing using jquery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use following way ,use fadeIn,fadeOut ,Check link [Fadein](http://api.jquery.com/fadein/)
[Fadeout](http://api.jquery.com/fadeout/)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type='text/javascript'>
var imageID=0;
function changeimage(every_seconds){
    //change the image
    $("#myimage").fadeOut();
    $("#myimage").fadeIn();
    if(!imageID){
        document.getElementById("myimage").src="http://www.all-freeware.com/images/full/38943-nice_feathers_free_screensaver_desktop_screen_savers__nature.jpeg";
        imageID++;
    }
    else{if(imageID==1){
        document.getElementById("myimage").src="http://www.hickerphoto.com/data/media/186/flower-bouquet-nice_12128.jpg";
        imageID++;
    }else{if(imageID==2){
        document.getElementById("myimage").src="http://www.photos.a-vsp.com/fotodb/14_green_cones.jpg";
        imageID=0;
    }}}
    //call same function again for x of seconds
    setTimeout("changeimage("+every_seconds+")",((every_seconds)*1000));
}
</script>
</head>
<body style='background:black;' onload='changeimage(2)'>
<div style='position:absolute;width:100%;height:100%;left:0px;top:0px;' align='center'><img width='300px' height='250px' id='myimage' src='http://www.photos.a-vsp.com/fotodb/14_green_cones.jpg'/></div>
</body></html>
```

Answer (score 0):

The trick is to fade out one while fading in another.

With jQuery, it's very easy, otherwise you might need to code the animation yourself, or try to use CSS transition.

Generally, you can use the opacity property for this.